# Actionscript 3.0 Reg Exp Find first URL, Ignore Email

Tags: html, regex, actionscript-3, email

I've got a bit of code where I have a loop with a string.search() to parse a string of HTML.  The purpose is to seek out any valid URLs and surround each one with HREF tags appropriately while ignoring anything else, like email addresses.  The problem is no matter how I modify the regular expression, it either kicks back the part of the email address after the @ sign and highlights it or it highlights or ignores everything.

An example string would be:

`"</span><span class='blue'>Weaselgrease:</span><span class='magenta'>weaselgrease@weasel.grs vs weaselgrease.weasel.grs</span><span class='blue'> [12:41:33 AM]</span>"`

Where 'weaselgrease.weasel.grs' would be identified as a proper URL and 'weaselgrease@weasel.grs' would be ignored.

The code I have currently is `/([fh]t{1,2}ps?:\/\/)?[\w-]+\.\w{2,4}/`

I know it's rather simple, but it doesn't need to be complex yet.

I've tried a conditional and gotten nowhere.  I may just be missing something, but my searching and even playing legos with http://regex101.com/ has gotten me no closer.

Ultimately I'm going to have it do the following:
   Identify a valid URL's index in the string
   Ignore if it's an email
   Ignore if it's just an IP address (no prepending http:// and no trailing slash)

But I'd be happy with just an inkling of help on what I need to do to get it to ignore email addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL without proper protocol (i.e. http, https, ftp) cannot be validated as such, because this means that almost everything that has `.` (dot) in it is a valid url.

So there is not a way to properly check if it's url or e-mail if you don't use the protocol. Example:

end of sentence.New sentence -> `sentence.New` is valid url in your case
weaselgrease@weasel.grs -> everything before `@` is ignored and `weasel.grs` is valid url

Comment: Inappropriate URLs are fine.  I don't mind if 'potato.cake.skittles.sumo' is a match.  All I'm looking to do is have it so that if @ is present before the first 'word.', it considers that string to not match.  So that '@big.chocolate.one' and 'big@chocolate.one' would not be a match, but 'big.chocolate.one' would be.

Comment: If you think through your idea, you will see the problem - you start to reply on dots and spaces to be your delimeters. `big@chocolate.one` is actually a match for `chocolate.one`. So you are looking for whole groups of characters that are separated by punctuation signs and you search if `@` is inside. I can write that for you, but I think it's a mess and won't work properly.

Comment: While I was looking around I've seen methods for searching through a string with a lookahead and a lookbehind at the ends of the regex to make the search exclusive against specific words or characters.  The problem I ran into with AS is that lookbehinds have to be zero-width, so I can't use * or + where the examples showed (obviously, the examples were for a different language).  I was really interested in seeing if there was a method for accomplishing it without having to issue an if-then in regular actionscript code, but I guess that's the route I'll have to take.  Thanks for your help!